# How to use namespace returned by parse_known_args?

Tags: python, parsing, replace

I am currently writing a Python script and trying to dynamically generate some arguments. However, an error is being thrown for the following script, stating `'Namespace' object is not iterable.` Any ideas on how to fix?

```
import argparse
from os import path
import re

replacements = {}
pattern = '<<([^>]*)>>'

def user_replace(match):
   ## Pull from replacements dict or prompt
    placeholder = match.group(1)
    return (replacements[placeholder][0] 
         if placeholder in replacements else 
          raw_input('%s? ' % placeholder))

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infile', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('outfile', type=argparse.FileType('w'))

    required, extra = parser.parse_known_args()
    infile, outfile = required.infile, required.outfile
    args = re.findall(pattern, infile.read())
    args = list(set(args))
    infile.seek(0)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    for arg in args:
        parser.add_argument('--' + arg.lower())

    replacements = vars(parser.parse_args(extra))

    matcher = re.compile(pattern)

    for line in args.infile:
        new_line = matcher.sub(user_replace, line)
        args.outfile.write(new_line)

    args.infile.close()
    args.outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error is with the returned value of parser.parse_known_args(). Any ideas on how I could bypass this though? Someone suggested creating an object and using the **dict** interface, but I don't know what this entails exactly. I'm really new to Python, so I don't understand why (infile, outfile), extra = parser.parse_known_args() wouldn't work.

Edit: Updated with two fixes. First fixed the error above by using the accepted answer below. Second, also fixed an error where I was getting flagged for trying to add the same argument twice. Fixed by making args a set then back to a list. Now my script runs, but the optional arguments have no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Already answered this on your original question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`ArgumentParser.parse_known_args`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) returns a *namespace* and a list of the remaining arguments. Namespaces aren't iterable, so when you try to assign one to the tuple `(infile, outfile)` you get the "not iterable" error.

Instead, you should write something like

```
namespace, extra = parser.parse_known_args()
```

and then access the parsed arguments as `namespace.infile` and `namespace.outfile`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with the parse_args() method. I wanted to use the namespace as a dictionary. Since it looks like a dict, it should be possible!

```
args = parser.parse_args()
for k, v in args: -> "'Namespace' object is not iterable."
for k, v in dict(args): -> "'Namespace' object is not iterable."

for k, v in args.__dict__.iteritems():
    print(k, v) # Works!

# Or just use it as any other dictionary
d.update(args.__dict__)
f(**args.__dict__)
```

Comment: `vars()` is the canonical way to convert an object's attribs to a dict...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that line of code should read as follows:

```
namespace= parser.parse_known_args()
```

Otherwise, one still gets the error about namespaces not being iterable.